# Why don't new mongoid fields show up when adding them to model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I added new fields to a model.

Then i do rake db:drop

I inspect the database and only the old fields are there. Why are the new fields not added?

Comment: Are you adding content to the new fields? And also some code might help...

Comment: will show new fields only once you create or update anything in that particular table, As mongoDB will create fields on the fly... :)

Comment: @Jyothu I create new records, but the fields are not there

Comment: It was params.require(

Comment: Can you show us the code you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: because MongoDB isn't a relational database, and collections are not tables. You need to get familiar with basic MongoDB concepts before you start using it.

Comment: no, it was params.require( blocking. i don't need to do anything

Comment: @hunterp if it was so than your question was very ill formed. Based on your question, the answer seems to be in the right direction, although it could have been more explanatory.